# Establishing synchronized music streaming across devices

Tags: ios, audio, streaming, buffer, firebase

I am attempting to stream audio files from a server to iOS devices and play them completely synchronized. For example on my phone I might be 20 secs into a song and then my friend next to me should also be 20 secs into the song as well. I know this is not an easy problem to solve, but I am attempting to do so.

I can currently get them within one second of each other by calculating the difference in time between the devices and then have them sync up, however that is not good enough because the human ear can detect a major difference in a second and this is over WIFI.

My next approach is going to be to unicast the one file from the server and then have the all devices pick it up directly from the server and then implement some type of buffer system similar to netflix so that network connectivity would be a limiting factor. http://www.wowza.com/ is what I would use to help with that.

I know this can be done, because http://lysn.in/ is does it with their app and I want to be able to do something similar.

Any other recommendations after I try my unicast option?

Would implementing firebase help solve a lot of the heavy lifting problems?

Comment: Are you using AVPlayer or low level solution?

Comment: AVPlayer is what I am using.

Comment: in your current solution. when you synchronize the time with seekToTime? when creating the player or after AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay event? seconds in int or in double?

Comment: Yes over the internet. Yes they are talking directly over the same internet. Yes the music file is currently coming from the internet server.

Comment: hi @WillJamieson - would you mind to Tick any useful answer to keep the board tidy - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

(1) In answer to ONE of your questions (the final one):

Firebase is not "realtime" in "that sense" -- PubNub is probably (almost certainly) the fastest "realtime" messaging for and between apps/browser/etc.

But they don't mean real-time in the sense of real-time, say, as race game engineers mean it or indeed in your use-case.

So Firebase is not relevant to you here and won't help.

(2) Regarding your second general question: "how to synchronise time on two or more devices, given that we have communications delays."

Now, this is a really well-travelled problem in computer science.

It would be pointless outlining it here, because it is [fully explained here](http://www.ntp.org/ntpfaq/NTP-s-algo.htm), if you click on "How is time synchronised"?

So in fact, to get a good time base on both machines, **you should use that**!  Have both machines really accurately set a time to NTP using the existing (perfected for decades) NTP synchronisation.

(So for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/6744978/294884).

In fact are you doing this?

It's possible that doing that will solve all your problems; then just agree to start at a certain exact time.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend against using the data movement to synchronize the playback. This should be straightforward to do with a buffer and a periodic "sync" signal that is sent at a period of < 1/2 the buffer size. Worst case this should generate a small blip on devices that get ahead or behind relative to the sync signal.